# How to implement Logout in an Android application

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

Which is the best efficient way to implement the logout functionality in android application ?

**Here is my logout code**

```
 public void logOut(){
    Prefs.getPreferences().edit().clear().apply();
    finish();
    startActivity(new Intent(this,LoginActivity.class));
}
```

Comment: You need check current token if not exits then proceed to logout to user. For this approach you need to save token in shared Preference.

Comment: Just remove user token and related data and navigate back to login screen

Comment: @Bach Vu  please explain how to do it.